# remove line is no characters after delimiter

Tags: scripting, sed, awk, lines

I have a file with three delimiters of ';' - If there is no text after the third delimiter, I need to delete the line. Any ideas how to do this?

```
blahDI-blah.john;fdfds;gfdg;gdfgf
DNSK-ECAA.paul;ghdfdgd;fdsd;
```

Returns only

```
blahDI-blah.john;fdfds;gfdg;gdfgf
```

Thanks as always!
Steve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another `awk`

```
awk '!/;$/' file
blahDI-blah.john;fdfds;gfdg;gdfgf
```

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
awk -F";" '$4' file
```

This will print those lines in which the 4th column is not empty.

Comment: brilliant! i need to learn awk properly. how about deleting everything between the second and third delimiter?

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
sed '/;$/d' file
```

Using `grep`

```
grep -v ';$' file
```

Using `awk` (Another variants are in Guru and Jotne's ans)

```
awk '/;$/ {next} 1' file
```

All of above will remove lines ending with `;`

Output:

```
blahDI-blah.john;fdfds;gfdg;gdfgf
```